# How can i find top N rows with unique column value, ordered by another columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have a table like this

```
create table a_table
(
    id         int unique,
    filter_val text,
    sort_val   text
);

insert into a_table(id, filter_val, sort_val)
values (1, 'a3', 'a2'),
       (2, 'a4', 'a3'),
       (3, 'a5', 'a4'),
       (4, 'a3', 'a1'),
       (5, 'a2', 'a3');
```

How can I select a top N unique values `filter_val`, but ordered by `sort_val`?
As example, if I select top 3 unique value it equals 'a3','a4','a2'.
Top 4 values is 'a3','a'4','a2','a5'.

I`m trying to use `select distinct filter_val`, but it forbid a `order by sort_val`.

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: @jarlh, thank you. 
Result is top N values of `filter_val`, but ordered by `sort_val`
For example, top 2 values it is 3,4. Top 3 values is 3,4,2. Top 4 values is 3,4,2,5. Top 1 value is 3.
Result may be row set, or array, not matter. Only order by `sort_val` is needed.

Comment: "Top 4 values is 3,4,2,5" there is no way to get this order with this sample data, try to improve your question

Comment: @a801a28cb4b6e70a I`m sorry, it is. 
I update question.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL also has [DISTINCT ON](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/postgresql-distinct-on-expression/)

> ```
> select *
> from
> (
>   select distinct on (filter_val) *
>   from a_table
>   order by filter_val asc, sort_val
> ) q
> order by sort_val
> limit 4;
> ```

| id | filter_val | sort_val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | a3 | a1 |
| 5 | a2 | a3 |
| 2 | a4 | a3 |
| 3 | a5 | a4 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f0c234ba8ec2d1b0354c50f3367b120a)*